# Send a message to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, model-view-controller

I am really breaking my head on this issue I have. Let's assume I have three classes in my app; `Player`, `Game` and `GameViewController`.

In the player class I have an `NSMutableArray` with cards, which I named `playerCards`. In the game setup (`Game` class) I add cards to the `playerCards` array by sending a message to the `Player` class `[player drawCard]`, which adds cards to the array. Working OK, the array gets filled with cards. To be clear; in the `Game` class I allocated and initiated a `Player` instance.

In the `GameViewController` I want to add the `playerCards` array to a `UITableView` and here is where it comes complicated, at least for me. I cannot send a message to the `Player` class without allocating and initiating another `Player` class. But this does not make any sense to me. Let's assume I have a single player game, then I only have one instance of the `Player` class right? I can, however, get it to work to make a new `NSMutableArray` in the `Game` class and tell it to be the `playerCardsArray` and then in `GameViewController` (where I allocated an instance of the `Game` class), I send a message to the array in the `Game` instance. But this seems sloppy to me, sending messages via via.

So my question basically comes down to, how do I use the `playerCards` in the `objectAtIndex` methods of the `UITableView` in `GameViewController`?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `GameViewController` you should have a reference to the `Game` object. This `Game` object could hold an `NSArray` of `players`, where each item is of type `Player`.

Within your `GameViewController` you could ask the `Game` instance for their `players`. Then you ask for the cards of a specific `Player` instance.

```
NSArray *players = [self.game players];
NSArray *playerCards = nil;
// assume you want to access the first player
if([players count] > 0) {
    Player *firstPlayer = players[0];
    playerCards = firstPlayer.playerCards;
}
// do whatever you have to do with the player's cards
```

Looks fine to me.

Comment: Enlightening, thanks! Also thanks for the edit. I will pay more attention to the formatting next time.